# Remove square bracket([ ]) in json file node JS

Tags: node.js, json, express, lodash

I want to remove square bracket "[ ]" in json object or concatenate some array of object to one array of object.

This code for counting current stock

```
currentStock : ( req, res, next) => {

    var listed_item = _(arr_items).map( (z) => {

        var result = module.exports.getTransactionAfterDate(z.created_at, z.item_id);

        return result;

    })

    var jsonContent = JSON.stringify(listed_item);

    return res.send(jsonContent);
},


getTransactionAfterDate : (date, item_id) => {

    var result = _(db_transaction).filter( (x) => {

        return x.created_at > date && x.item_id == item_id;

    });

    return result;

}
```

this is "listed_item" json result

```
[
    [{
        "id": 30608,
        "item_id": "A01001",
        "quantity": 150,
        "status": "OUT",
        "created_at": "2020-02-10 16:11:51",
    }],
    [],
    [{
        "id": 30412,
        "item_id": "A02001",
        "quantity": 53,
        "status": "OUT",
        "created_at": "2020-02-06 14:44:20",
    }, {
        "id": 30482,
        "item_id": "A02001",
        "quantity": 33,
        "created_at": "2020-02-07 15:26:50",
        "updated_at": "2020-02-07 15:26:50",
    }]
]
```

what i want is like this

```
[
    {
        "id": 30608,
        "item_id": "A01001",
        "quantity": 150,
        "status": "OUT",
        "created_at": "2020-02-10 16:11:51",
    },
    {
        "id": 30412,
        "item_id": "A02001",
        "quantity": 53,
        "status": "OUT",
        "created_at": "2020-02-06 14:44:20",
    }, {
        "id": 30482,
        "item_id": "A02001",
        "quantity": 33,
        "created_at": "2020-02-07 15:26:50",
        "updated_at": "2020-02-07 15:26:50",
    }
]
```

**note**
i tried concatenate "getTransactionAfterDate" inside "arr_items" map to join all array inside

```
var temp = [];
var listed_item = _(arr_items).map( (z) => {

    temp = _(temp).concat(module.exports.getTransactionAfterDate(z.created_at, z.item_id));
    var result = temp;

    return result;

})
```

but the result is empty array

```
[ [], [], [] ]
```

Comment: it is not clear what `_(arr_items)` and `_(db_transaction)` are!!

Comment: arr_items is list of item id

Comment: db_transaction is table of transaction, if i put all of that here it will be full of code :)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```js
currentStock : ( req, res, next) => {
    var items = [];

    _(arr_items).forEach( (z) => {

        var result = module.exports.getTransactionAfterDate(z.created_at, z.item_id);

        result.forEach( item => {
          items.push(item);
        }

    })

    var jsonContent = JSON.stringify(items);

    return res.send(jsonContent);
},
```

Comment: note: this is not the optimal way to solve the problem especially for large amounts of data. So, if you may need to find a better solution in the future.

Comment: can you give me exapmle optimal method?

Answer (score 1):

You can 'flatten' the array with lodash, which will just merge all the arrays into a single one:

```
_(arr).flatten()
```

That should then give you a single array of your objects, with no empty arrays either.

`.flatten()` in the lodash docs here: https://lodash.com/docs/#flatten

So it would be something like this (*edited based on comments*):

```
currentStock : ( req, res, next) => {

    var listed_item = _(arr_items).map( (z) => {

        var result = module.exports.getTransactionAfterDate(z.created_at, z.item_id);

        return result;

    })

    var flattened = _(listed_item).flatten();

    var jsonContent = JSON.stringify(flattened);

    return res.send(jsonContent);
},
```

Nice and simple! (if I correctly understood what you are trying to do :-)

Comment: after i read the doc of flatten, i want that. but i tried it to my code nothing change when i flatten "listed_item"

Comment: I think per your example, you should flatten `arr_items`, not `listed_item`, right? You should probably flatten it first, then if you want to filter by transaction date, do that *after* it is flattened.

Comment: can i flatten the `listed_item`? before `json.stringify`

Comment: Yes, flatten it *before* -- json.stringify should be *after* all your data processing

Comment: i do `_(listed_item).flatten()` but nothing changes

Comment: I updated that whole method in my answer based on that. If that is still not working, maybe paste your updated code that you are using

Comment: i do your method but nothing change. with flatten it should be solve my problem, but i dont know why it didnt work

Comment: **AZ_SH** answer give what i want, but i curious using lodash to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

this can be done with the combination of `_.flatten` (for this lodash is required) and `Array.prototype.filter` like shown below

```
let newArray = _.flatten(listed_item.filter(e => e.length > 0))
```